# Split an array into even chunks based on integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This might be a duplicate, though I didn't find any questions specific to my problem here.

<s>Say I have an array like this</s>

```
var hundred = [1,2,3,4,5...100]
```

This array has 100 elements. From 1 to 100.

Based on an integer, how can I split this array into another array with the same amount of elements, except they've been evenly distributed like this?

```
var integer = 2;
var hundred = [50,50,50,50,50,50...100,100,100,100,100,100]
```

In this example, the array has 50 elements with the value 50, and 50 elements with the value 100, because the integer was 2.

I'm bad at math, so this might be incorrect, but I hope you understand what I mean. The array must have the same ammount of indexes after the calculation.

## Edit (Due to me being very bad at formulating questions, I'm going to use the code I need this for here):

So I have a frequencybin array (from the AudioContext analyser):

```
var fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
```

This array has a set number of elements ( They are the frequencies of audio played ).

Now I have a spectrum analyser, which has a set number of "bars" so if I have only 3 bars, then how can I split the fbc_array so that each bar has the evenly distributed frequency in it? For example, with 3 bars, bar one would have the bass, bar two would have the mids, bar three would have the treble.

I'm using a for loop for iterating over each bar:

```
for (i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * canspace;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -3 - (fbc_array[i] / 2);
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
```

Comment: The explanation is not clear.

Comment: What exactly is it you don't understand?

Comment: How the input turns into output. What is the logic between turning `[1,2,3...100]` into `[50,50,50,..., 100,100,100]`

Comment: @zerkms That's why I am asking that question. Because I need to know what that logic is. If you need a real life situation, I am using the WebAudioApi to get the frequency bin of a sound into an array in wich I need to split into evenly sized chunks, with the same amount of elements.

Comment: Is the output of the 100 indexes supposed to be random? Like, if I passed in integer = 3, could I get 20 (33 times), 41 (33 times) and 67 (33 times)?

Comment: @lmforshizley Yes! Exactly that!

Comment: So, the values picked might be random?

Comment: So what would be the desired output if `integer` was 3? Bearing in mind that 100 doesn't divide evenly into 3 groups...

Comment: This is not possible in some cases, where `integer%handered.length > 0` suppose 3 for example.

Comment: @nnnnnn If the output isn't evenly divided, you could always round it.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=const%20input%20%3D%20new%20Array(100).fill(0).map((_%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20i%20%2B%201)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20flat%20%3D%20arrays%20%3D%3E%20%5B%5D.concat(...arrays)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20integer%20%3D%203%3B%0A%0Aconst%20output%20%3D%20flat(new%20Array(integer)%0A%20%20.fill(0).map((_%2C%20i)%20%3D%3E%20i%20%2B%201)%0A%20%20.map(v%20%3D%3E%20new%20Array(Math.floor(input.length%20%2F%20integer)).fill(v)))%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(output)%0A%20%20%0A ?

Comment: What is the input, exactly? `integer`? The length of `hundred`? The elements of `hundred`?

Comment: I've added my actual problem into the question to make it better to understand this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still lacking a big logical component. We realize there will only be 2 of the same number in the output array, but how are the numbers in the output generated? Randomly?

Comment: MDN [AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) with example code for displaying a bar graph.

Answer (score 1):

(Written before your update, so guessing here).

You're looking for a way to approximate a graph so that it's divided into bands and each point within a band is replaced with that band's maximum:

[image]

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(fn) {
  var a = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this; i++)
    a.push(fn(i));
  return a;
}



function approximate(src, n) {

  var res = [], 
      size = Math.ceil(src.length / n), 
      i = 0;
  
  
  while(i < src.length) {
    var chunk = src.slice(i, i += size)
    var p = Math.max.apply(null, chunk);
    
    // this gives you an average instead of maximum
    // p = chunk.reduce((x, y) => x + y) / chunk.length;
    
    res = res.concat(size.times(i => p));
  }
  
  return res;

}



src = 20..times(i => 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 80));

res = approximate(src, 4);

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(src));
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: He doesn't want a 2-dimensional result, so you need to concatenate the results.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but I just need to do all this based on an array (the frequency bin or graph if you will) see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode

Comment: @SebastianOlsen: it is based on an array (`src` in my snippet).

Comment: Did this answer your question? I'm still available to help you but your question still calls for more information. Best of luck.

Comment: @lmforshizley I'm still struggling, if you still want to help me then I think that's very kind, maybe we could take it over chat? I feel like I'm better at explaining when I talk directly with someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I gathered from this craziness! Sorry you're having trouble conveying your problem. That's always a headache! Good luck.

```
//set integer to whatever you want
var integer = 3;
var randomNumber;
var output = new Array()

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
 randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for(i = 0; i<integer;i++){
  getRandomIntInclusive(1,100);
  for(j = 1; j< (100/integer); j++){
    output.push(randomNumber);
  }
}

//note, you will not always get 100 array items
//you can check with console.log(output.length);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What is randomNumber here? Is it the input array?

Comment: randomNumber is a random number between 1 - 100. It will never be 0.

Comment: It's the same as using the input array, if the numbers are always 1, 2, 3...100.

Comment: The thing is the frequencybin count definitely has more than 100 and it might vary depending on browser, is it possible to not hardcode that?

Comment: Does the frequencybin count come in as a javascript array, as you've hinted at above?

Comment: Yes. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104219/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-imforshizley).